# Why are 6 # Marks Being Produced in This Code?

Tags: c, cs50

I have a problem that needs some explaining.

When I run the code below, I will be asked for 3 values: height, width, and widthtwo. If I enter 1 for height, 2 for width, and 2 for widthtwo, 6 # marks are produced on just one line, like this "######"--without the quotations marks, obviously. I don't understand why 6 are being produced. I would expect 4 # marks to be the product. Please help!

After running with the aforementioned values, ###### will be the product.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = get_int("Height of Pyramid?");
    int width = get_int("Length of Width?");
    int widthtwo = get_int("Length of Widthtwo?");
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {   
            for (int a = 0; a < widthtwo; a++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }

            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: (2 because of widthtwo + 1 the next line) *2 because of width

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 2nd printf("#"); line.  This is adding the two extra # since it is called every time in the j loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {   
        for (int a = 0; a < widthtwo; a++)
        {
            printf("#");   // Executed 1*2*2 times 
        }

        printf("#");       // Executed 1*2 times - Remove this line
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This may help you visualize it:

```
i j a
0 0 0 #
0 0 1 ##
0 0 1 ### (last # is from 2nd printf)
0 1 0 ####
0 1 1 #####
0 1 1 ###### (last # is from 2nd print)
```

Comment: In what order does the compiler execute the code? For example, will it read a = 0 first, check the boolean next, execute the first printf, then execute the second printf, then increment a, and do that over?

If it does that, then 4 # marks are produced. After executing that code, will it then run the int j part, producing two more # marks?

If it does it in that order, I think I see why 6 # marks are produced.

Comment: I updated my answer with some information that hopefully helps you.  The 2nd printf will be called after the "a" loop is completed.  Since this printf is not needed just get rid of it and your code will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop runs once - only when i = 0.
So all the other code enclosed in the block (and inside that loop) will run once.

The inner 'j' loop will run twice in total, when j=0 and when j=1. Each time it runs,
the innermost 'a' loop runs twice, and it prints '#' once each time. That would be (2 x 2)  4 '#'s printed.

But after the 'a' loop has run twice, each time the program will execute the printf("#") line which is inside the 'j' loop, and which runs after the 'a' loop. So once for each time the 'j' loop iterates - i.e. twice - and that means another 2 x '#'.